# SSH or Console does not work on a google instance with multiple NICs due to improper routing

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a compute instance with 2 NICs (nic0 and nic1) connected to two different VPCs (vpc0 and vpc1).

nic0 is connected to vpc0
nic1 is connected to vpc1

vpc0 has subnet 192.168.1.0/24
vpc1 has subnet 172.16.0.1/12

vpc0 has route only for 192.168.1.0/24
vpc1 has a default route to the internet - 0.0.0.0/0 (along with 172.16.0.0/12)

The intention is that the public access is only via nic1 of the instance via vpc1. However when I create an ubuntu instance with this config, I am not able to SSH (or use the console or ping). The routing is messed up. I cannot get in through nic0 either.

I understand that gcp adds only route for nic0, the documentation here https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/create-use-multiple-interfaces says to adjust the route to nic1, but for that I need to be able to ssh.

On the documentation page, there is paragraph that says 
"I am not able to connect to secondary interface using external IP
The DHCP server programs a default route only on the primary network interface of the VM. If you want to connect to the secondary interface using an external IP, there are two options. **If you only need to connect outside the network on the secondary network interface, you can set a default route on that network interface.** Otherwise, you can use Configuring Policy Routing to configure a separate routing table using source-based policy routing in your VM."

How do I set the default route on the network interface nic1? Setting the route on the vpc does not seem to help.

I logged into the instance through another instance on the same network and was able to see that the problem instance had a default route to internet via nic0 (192.168.0.1). I tried to remove this route via startup script and add a new route through nic1 from the startup script, but that does not seem to work either. The route via nic0 gets removed, but the one via nic1 is not added.

I don't know how to fix this if ssh (or ping or console access) does not work. This is a routing problem and I want to be able to adjust the route. In the end, I want to be able to instantiate an instance with two nics, and the internet access to be on nic1 instead of nic0 without having to ssh into the machine and fix the route. I wish startup script had worked.

Comment: Could you provide the startup scripts ?? And what do you mean by "Setting the route on the vpn does not seem to help" - what VPN ?

Comment: sorry I meant to say vpc, not vpn. I have correct the post now. The startup script I used is

#! /bin/bash
sudo ip route del default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
sudo ip route add default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth1
EOF

Answer (score 1):

If you created a VM with NIC0 attached to VPC0, and NIC1 to VPC1 then it won't work without some configuration at Linux level (because you'r VPC0 has no Internet access) and VPC1 does.

I've tested it and was able to replicate the issue you're having.

In my case the solution was to create a VM with NIC0 attached to the network with internet access (in your case it's VPC1) and NIC1 attached to VPC0. That way NIC0 gets configured automatically when VM starts and has Internet access - while NIC1 provides conectivity to VPC0.

---

EDIT - 11/13/2019

You can alternatively add custom route every time this VM starts by adding a line in .bashrc; login to this VM from another box an type:

```
sudo nano .bashrc
```

and add at the end of the file one line:

```
sudo route add default gw 172.16.0.1
```

I assume that 172.16.0.1 is your gateway in VPC1.

Reload the .bashrc file:

```
source .bashrc
```

and ping for example google.com - you should see response times :)

I've tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 but my method also should work on older versions.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I cannot use that config because I want to use an Network Load Balancer, which can only use nic0 on the VM instance. So. I want to use nic0 on vpc0 as a data network, and nic1 on vpc1 as a management network.

Comment: I've edited my reply to include alternative solution for adding custom route every time VM starts by modifying .bashrc file - check it out and post your feedback.

Comment: Thank you @Wojciech. That's a good idea and I think it should work. Let me try this out and update  you.

Comment: the solution that worked, with help from google engineer, was to replace routes in startup script and  use a dhcp exit hook to prevent dhcp from overwriting network config. see https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/guest-agent/issues/76#issuecomment-693574946 for more details on dhclient-down-hooks workaround.